# Error: "prettier/react" has been merged into "prettier" in eslint-config-prettier 8.0.0

Tags: reactjs

Cannot read config file error

Cannot read config file: G:\chat app\chat-app\node_modules\eslint-config-prettier\react.js Error: "prettier/react" has been merged into "prettier" in eslint-config-prettier 8.0.0. See: https://github.com/prettier/eslint-config-prettier/blob/main/CHANGELOG.md#version-800-2021-02-21 Referenced from: G:\chat app\chat-app\.eslintrc

Comment: Did you read the link? What's your question?

Answer (score 11):

[.eslintrc config](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hZgJl.png)

Remove "prettier/react"
Also remove all extents with "prettier/" since all the required configs are merged with "prettier"